# Jquery Trigger Scroll Event Once

Tags: jquery

I have this slightly convoluted code.  Essentially, once the user scrolls down past the height of a certain div, it sets the display of an object to none, changes some CSS selectors and fades the element in.  The else statement should handle when the user scrolls up past that same height, the item should fade out, change CSS selectors, and then reappear by changing display to a visible option.  The reason it does this, is because it is changing the element from static to fixed.  Once you scroll past the static element you can no longer see on the viewport, it is set to display: none; and fixed, so that it can fade in as a fixed element on the viewport.  Vice versa with the reverse.  The problem, is that the onscroll event is fired every single time I scroll above the specified height, causing the event to flicker in and out every single time I scroll.  What I want, is for each event to fire only a single time, upon the passing of the specified scroll height, once, for either direction.  Is that possible?

```
(function($) {          
    $(document).ready(function(){   

        $(window).off().scroll(function(){

            if ($(this).scrollTop() > $("#carousel").outerHeight()) {

                $("#nav").css("display", "none");
                ...modifying css, etc etc
                $('#nav').fadeIn(500);

            } else {

                $('#nav').fadeOut(500); 
                ...modifying css, etc etc
                $("#nav").css("display", "static");

        }
    });
});

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > $("#carousel").outerHeight()) && $("#nav").hasClass("topclass")) {

                $("#nav").css("display", "none");
                ...modifying css, etc etc
                $('#nav').fadeIn(500);

            } else if ($(this).scrollTop() < $("#carousel").outerHeight() &&    $("#nav").hasClass("bottomclass")) {

                $('#nav').fadeOut(500); 
                ...modifying css, etc etc
                $("#nav").css("display", "static");

            }
```

Here is a solution - it doesn't use special event binding or anything, though gets the job done by checking whether or not the class has already been set, thus there being no reason to fire the event multiple times.